# Upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04; No desktop, no panels appearing

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, gnome-panel

I am able to log in to Gnome(Classic) and I can use a terminal command there. However, whenever I try to log in to Ubuntu, my terminal command doesn't work. My guest session does not work either. I was able to get rid of the System Program Problem Detected alert. My mouse works. Once I log in, all I see on the bottom left is the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS sign.

Also, after running

```
dconf reset -f /org/complex
setsid unity
```

I get the following:

```
Info: Unity is not supported by your hardware. Enabling software rendering instead (slow).
```

What can I do to get my launchpad and panels back?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Comment: Well, if unity not supported, I guess you could try something other than unity , like xfce or lxde desktops. My personal favorite is cinnamon. More info here http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available

Answer (score -1):

I had this happen to me also this is what I did hope it helps

- I updated the Graphics Drivers by doing the following
- Enter Recovery Mode
- Go to System Settings
- Go to Software and Updates
- Additional Drivers tab
- I picked one of the recommended drives rebooted and it worked

---

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I am unsure what the part (List item) is.